# Python movement of hands on analogue clock

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to draw a clock face in which the second hand moves as the time changes.
I am using the following to calculate the points on my circle:

```
def points_on_circle():
global time, radius, centre, x, y

theta = time% math.pi * 2
c = math.cos(theta)
s = math.sin(theta)
x= centre[0] + radius * c
y =centre[1] + radius * s
return x,y
```

my timer 'ticks' every tenth second, the radius of my circle is 50, the centre is at (150,150) which is also the origin of my hand, the other end of the hand being (x,y) as calculated above. How do I calculate , I assume by multiplying time by some constant, how fast the x,y should change for this circle ( but for any circle) .
I am using CodeSkulptor from Coursera  to try to do this ( the original assignment created a digital timer which I am done. This is not part of the homework ( yet??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hand rotates 2 Pi radians every 60 seconds.  Assuming you're syncing with real time, time.time() will return the current time in seconds (and milliseconds which I suggest you ignore).  If you take the time and first do `numseconds = int(time.time()) % 60`, you now need to translate that, which is a simple as numseconds * 2 * pi / 60.  (Example: numseconds = 0, theta = 0, numseconds = 15, theta = pi /2 (90 degrees).

You will also need to play with your equations as normally theta=0 implies the line is horizontal pointing right (which would be numseconds = 15) and theta=Pi implies the line is vertical pointing up (which would be numseconds = 0)